# How can I extract text with <br> delimiters?

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri

How can I extract from this HTML code:

```
<body>
  <div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
      <div class="div3">
        <div class="div3.1">
          <h2 class="notopgap">HEADER</h2>
          <br>DONT WANT THIS TEXT
          <br><a href='mailto:info@mylink.pt'>info@mylink.pt</a>
          <br><h2>I WANT THIS TEXT</h2>
          <br>TEXT: WANT THIS
          <br>DONT WANT THIS
          <a name='#lev3'></a>
          <h2>FINALLY I WANT THIS TOO</h2><br>
          <div class="div3.1.1">
            BUNCH OF TEXT ...
```

the following text:

```
WANT THIS TEXT
WANT THIS
FINALLY I WANT THIS TOO
```

with Nokogiri/Ruby?

I can extract between divs and other elements, but how can I do it when there are no divs between each part of the text I want, but only br's?

Comment: What distinguishes what you want from what you don't? In particular what determines that you want "TEXT: WANT THIS" but not "DONT WANT THIS"?

Comment: what distinguishes is the <br>TEXT: ... until the next <br>!

Comment: So you want the text that is followed by a `<br>` but not the text that is *not* followed by a `<br>`?

Comment: Your logic is not at all clear. It's great that you supplied sample input and desired output, but you have not clearly conveyed what makes some areas special and others not.

Answer (score 1):

To start with you can use the following xpath:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.xpath("//div[@class='div3.1']/h2[not(@class = 'notopgap')]").map(&:text)
```

Which will match the two `<h2>` tags that you want to extract. Extracting the other entry is more complex. My xpath kung fu is lacking on this front because it's at the same level as text you don't want to capture.

I would probably drop back to matching against the text.

```
text = doc.xpath("//div[@class='div3.1']").text()
text.scan(/TEXT:(.*)\n/).flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to keep it simple:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<body>
<div class="div1">
<div class="div2">
<div class="div3">
    <div class="div3.1">
        <h2 class="notopgap">HEADER</h2>
                <br>DONT WANT THIS TEXT
                <br><a href='mailto:info@mylink.pt'>info@mylink.pt</a>
                <br><h2>I WANT THIS TEXT</h2>
                <br>TEXT: WANT THIS
                <br>DONT WANT THIS
                <a name='#lev3'></a>
                <h2>FINALLY I WANT THIS TOO</h2><br>
                    <div class="div3.1.1">
EOT

h2 = doc.search('h2')
h2[1].text                            # => "I WANT THIS TEXT"
doc.search('br')[3].next_sibling.text # => "TEXT: WANT THIS\n                "
h2[2].text                            # => "FINALLY I WANT THIS TOO"
```

From that point it's easy to clean up the `"TEXT: WANT THIS\n                "`.

I know I'm going to have multiple hits, so rather than try to get where I want using XPath, a simple CSS will find the tags in question, then I can grab the particular one I want, and continue processing.

Comment: Unrelated to your answer: I like your Gravatar `Redundant\: See "redundant"` ;-)

Comment: @JamWaffles, LOL, you're the first to ever notice.